# Unable to unregister vms

Tags: awk, virtualbox

I have the following command to extract the name of virtual machines currently available in the host system.

```
vmslist=$(vboxmanage list vms | awk '{print $1}')
```

I pass this list to a for loop in order to unregister vms which are in the list as follwos:

```
for vm in $vmslist
do
    echo $vm
    vboxmanage controlvm $vm poweroff
    vboxmanage unregistervm $vm --delete
done
```

The problem is that the vboxmanage command complains about the names. For example it says:

```
VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine named '"SC-1"'
```

I don't understand where those single quotes around the name of vm come from!
How can I solve this?

Comment: Note that if I pass the id instead of name, the command works fine.

Comment: Please show the output of `vboxmanage list vms`

Comment: `"SC-1" {e539275c-862d-4399-b089-be44945027c2}`

Comment: First field is the name and the second one is the id of the machine.

Comment: So, do you need to strip off the quotes from `$vm` before you can use it as a parameter to vboxmanage?

Comment: The question is, why those single quotes are added to the name of vm?

Comment: Because they show up as plain characters in the "list" output. You have to manually remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just strip off the double quotes

```
vmslist=$(vboxmanage list vms | awk '{gsub(/"/, ""); print $1}')
```

And if the names could contain white space it would be important to quote the expansion.

```
for vm in $vmslist
do
    echo "$vm"
    vboxmanage controlvm "$vm" poweroff
    vboxmanage unregistervm "$vm" --delete
done
```